# How do i create an index in mongodb on a WHERE and ORDER query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In mongo, When creating an index I am trying to figure out whether the following query would have an index on a) category_ids and status, OR  b) category_ids, status and name???

```
Source.where(category_ids: [1,2,3], status: Status::ACTIVE).order_by(:name) # ((Ruby/Mongoid code))
```

Essentially, I am trying to figure out whether indexes should include the ORDER_BY columns? or only the WHERE clauses?  Where could I read some more about this?

Comment: Yes an index on this particular query would be more beneficial having both the query fields and the sort field in index. Here are afew good links: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/ http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-do-you-determine-what-fields-to-index http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2012/02/08/optimizing-mongodb-indexes/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329104/why-does-direction-of-index-matter-in-mongodb http://www.slideshare.net/kbanker/mongo-indexoptimizationprimer from a quick google search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an index on thius particular query would be beneficial to the speed of the query. However there is one caveat here, the order of the index fields.

I have noticed you are using an `$in` there on `category_ids`. This link is particularly useful in understanding a little complexity which exists from using an `$in` with an index on the sort (or a sort in general in fact): http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/

Towards the end it gives you an indea of an optimal index order for your type of query:

> The order of fields in an index should be:
>
> ```
> First, fields on which you will query for exact values.
> Second, fields on which you will sort.
> Finally, fields on which you will query for a range of values.
> ```

For reference a couple of other helpful links are as follows:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-do-you-determine-what-fields-to-index
- http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2012/02/08/optimizing-mongodb-indexes/
- [why does direction of index matter in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329104/why-does-direction-of-index-matter-in-mongodb)
- And, http://www.slideshare.net/kbanker/mongo-indexoptimizationprimer

These will help you get started on optimising your indexes and making them work for your queries.