# Avoiding duplicate entries in a mongoDB with Java and JSON objects

Tags: java, json, mongodb, twitter

I´m developing an analyzing program for Twitter Data.
I´m using mongoDB and at the moment. I try to write a Java program to get tweets from the Twitter API and put them in the database.
Getting the Tweets already works very well, but I have a problem when I want to put them in the database. As the Twitter API often returns just the same Tweets, I have to place some kind of index in the database.

First of all, I connect to the database and get the collection related to the search-term, or create this collection if this doesn´t exist.

```
public void connectdb(String keyword)
        {
            try {
                // on constructor load initialize MongoDB and load collection
                initMongoDB();
                items = db.getCollection(keyword);
                BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject("tweet_ID", 1);
                items.ensureIndex(index);



            } catch (MongoException ex) {
                System.out.println("MongoException :" + ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

Then I get the tweets and put them in the database:

```
public void getTweetByQuery(boolean loadRecords, String keyword) {

            if (cb != null) {
                TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
                try {
                    Query query = new Query(keyword);
                    query.setCount(50);
                    QueryResult result;
                    result = twitter.search(query);
                    System.out.println("Getting Tweets...");
                    List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

                    for (Status tweet : tweets) {

                        BasicDBObject basicObj = new BasicDBObject();
                        basicObj.put("user_name", tweet.getUser().getScreenName());
                        basicObj.put("retweet_count", tweet.getRetweetCount());
                        basicObj.put("tweet_followers_count", tweet.getUser().getFollowersCount());

                        UserMentionEntity[] mentioned = tweet.getUserMentionEntities();
                        basicObj.put("tweet_mentioned_count", mentioned.length);
                        basicObj.put("tweet_ID", tweet.getId());
                        basicObj.put("tweet_text", tweet.getText());


                        if (mentioned.length > 0) {
//                    System.out.println("Mentioned length " + mentioned.length + " Mentioned: " + mentioned[0].getName());
                        }
                        try {
                            items.insert(basicObj);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("MongoDB Connection Error : " + e.getMessage());
                            loadMenu();
                        }
                    }
                    // Printing fetched records from DB.
                    if (loadRecords) {
                        getTweetsRecords();
                    }

                } catch (TwitterException te) {
                    System.out.println("te.getErrorCode() " + te.getErrorCode());
                    System.out.println("te.getExceptionCode() " + te.getExceptionCode());
                    System.out.println("te.getStatusCode() " + te.getStatusCode());
                    if (te.getStatusCode() == 401) {
                        System.out.println("Twitter Error : \nAuthentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect.\nEnsure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Twitter Error : " + te.getMessage());
                    }


                    loadMenu();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("MongoDB is not Connected! Please check mongoDB intance running..");
            }
        }
```

But as I mentioned before, there are often the same tweets, and they have duplicates in the database.
I think the `tweet_ID` field is a good field for an index and should be unique in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`unique`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) option on your index to have MongoDb enforce uniqueness:

```
items.ensureIndex(index, new BasicDBObject("unique", true));
```

Note that you'll need to manually drop the existing index and remove all duplicates or you won't be able to create the unique index.

Comment: or put("dropDups", true) on that BasicDBObject you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered but I would like to contribute a bit since [MongoDB API 2.11](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.3/) offers a method which receives unique option as a parameter:

```
public void ensureIndex(DBObject keys, String name, boolean unique)
```

A minor remind to someone who would like to store json documents on MongoDBNote is that uniqueness must be applied to a BasicObject key and not over values. For example:

```
BasicDBObject basicObj = new BasicDBObject();
basicObj.put("user_name", tweet.getUser().getScreenName());
basicObj.put("retweet_count", tweet.getRetweetCount());
basicObj.put("tweet_ID", tweet.getId());
basicObj.put("tweet_text", tweet.getText());
basicObj.put("a_json_text", "{"info_details":{"info_id":"1234"},"info_date":{"year":"2012"}, {"month":"12"}, {"day":"10"}}");
```

On this case, you can create unique index only to basic object keys:

```
BasicDBObject index = new BasicDBObject();
int directionOrder = 1;
index.put("tweet_ID", directionOrder);
boolean isUnique = true;
items.ensureIndex(index, "unique_tweet_ID", isUnique);
```

Any index regarding JSON value like "info_id" would not work since it´s not a BasicObject key.

Using indexes on MongDB is not as easy as it sounds. You may also check MongoDB docs for more details here [Mongo Indexing Tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/) and [Mongo Index Concepts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/). Direction order might be pretty important to understand once you need a composed index which is well explained here [Why Direction order matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329104/why-does-direction-of-index-matter-in-mongodb).