# MongoDB index ascending or descending matter

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In MongoDB if I run a query like the following to get the latest trade:

```
db.trades.find({ sym: 'AAPL' }).sort({ d: -1 }).limit(1)
```

If the index on `d` is created as `{ d: 1 }`. I.E. does it matter if the index sort is ascending or descending? Also, I have an index on `sym` as well `{ sym: 1 }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does direction of index matter in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329104/why-does-direction-of-index-matter-in-mongodb)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142299/how-does-sorting-with-an-index-work-in-mongodb/36420196#36420196